# How to get the number of rows that contain a certain word?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So i have this code-generated table and i've been trying to get this code to work, basically i want to know how many rows have the word so i can later work with that number of elements, this code is like not working maybe you guys can see the error?
Code:

```
public int UntilArraySearch (String filtro){
    int tope=0;
    for(int i = 0;i<mTableLayout.getChildCount();i++){
        if(data[i].productName.contains(filtro) || data[i].productCode.contains(filtro))
            tope++;
    }
    return tope;
}
```

And this error pops up:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=52; index=52
```

I get this error whenever i run the function

Comment: Replace `mTableLayout.getChildCount()` to `mTableLayout.getChildCount() - 1`

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. What's the problem?

Comment: Nope i tried the "-1" and it's not working

Comment: Well the problem is that i can't see the problem haha, i tried the -1 and a different loop, didn't work

Comment: I can clearly see the problem is there

Comment: am i just blind?

Comment: Does `data[]` have 52 indexes?

Comment: Yes, it does!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop would work only if `mTableLayout.getChildCount()` is `<=` `data.length` and it seems that **it is not**, because if it was the case then `i` would not exceed the max index for `data`.

Since you want to iterate through `data`, why don't you write the loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i].productName.contains(filtro) || data[i].productCode.contains(filtro))
        tope++;
}
```

and check if this is the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching through `data`, then you might as well iterate over the length of the `data` array. Whether or not your view (`mTableLayout`) properly reflects the model (`data`), this operation can better isolate itself from the view by only considering the model which is a good practice to follow in general.

```java
public int UntilArraySearch (String filtro){
    int tope=0;
    for(int i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
        if(data[i].productName.contains(filtro) || data[i].productCode.contains(filtro))
            tope++;
    }
    return tope;
}
```